# String indexOf always return -1

Tags: javascript, filter, indexof

I'm in stuck while trying to filter an array using Array.filter method.

Please take a look into my code:

```
$scope.products = CachedData.Products.filter(function (item) {
    var itemNameSlug = Helpers.slug(item.Name); // eg: product100
    var keywordSlug = Helpers.slug($scope.keyword); // eg: p, pr, pro, duct etc...
    var result = itemNameSlug.indexOf(keywordSlug);
    console.log(result); // always -1
    return  result > -1;
});
```

When I type keyword as alphabet, it always return empty array (that indexOf return -1). If I type numeric, example is 1 or 10 or 100 or 00, i got correct result.

Why ?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: what is the result of console.log($scope.keyword, Helpers.slug($scope.keyword))?

Comment: Both are string. Please see comment in my code

Comment: clearly they are not both strings, otherwise result would not always be -1

Comment: Yes, eg: product100 and pro

Comment: I tried to dump variable type using typeof, both are string

Comment: does keywordSlug have any leading or trailing spaces?

Comment: No space, im sure. Very strange hix

Comment: please share a fiddle if possible

Comment: what is `console.log(itemNameSlug, typeof itemNameSlug)` and `console.log(keywordSlug, typeof keywordSlug)` ?

Comment: so, for numeric keywordSlug it works, that is strange and removes the possibility of some leading/trailing space ... I suggest console.log as @Maximus suggested to be 100% - because what you are describing is unpossible

Comment: Im sure, i was tried many times.

Comment: console.log('-' + itemNameSlug + '-', '-' + keywordSlug + '-', typeof itemNameSlug, typeof keywordSlug); => -product95 - -pro - string string

Comment: Oh no, i dont see last space from chrome dev tool. Eureka ! Thank you all mates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@trinvh according to the output in your comment, you're having a trailing space getting in the middle
when searching for the *needle* in the *haystack*, if the *needle* gets a trailing space, it would be impossible to match (since we are dealing here with slugs, which don't contain spaces)

```
/* according to your comment: */
console.log('-' + itemNameSlug + '-', '-' + keywordSlug + '-', typeof itemNameSlug, typeof keywordSlug);
/* gives: -product95 - -pro - string string */
```

then I would say the *needle* is "pro ", which won't match against "product95 "